# Can I make a 3D divs using any webgl libraries

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to create a div in 3D space which contains so many dom children, such that a form in a webgl canvas which can be edited and submitted.

Comment: WebGL is a rasterization library. It doesn't have anything to do with DIVs or other HTML elements except that it renders into a canvas element. So no, WebGL can't do this. See `3D CSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the div transformed in your 3d scene, you can use CSS3DObject:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh, rendererCSS;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 500;
  scene.add(camera);

  var number = document.createElement( 'div' );
  number.className = 'number';
  number.textContent = "THREE.JS";
  object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( number );

  scene.add(object);

  renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  object.rotation.x += 0.03;
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Here is the [complete demo](http://codepen.io/nireno/pen/giafd).

If you want to display a 2d form on top of all 3d graphics, then you can simply overlay a div with absolute position to the div that contains your WebGL canvas.